# RawQuerySet - Alias table columns are not coming in response

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Here is the code

```
query = 'SELECT  policy_agreement.*, policy.* from policy_agreement INNER JOIN policy ON policy_agreement.policy_id=policy.id WHERE policy.policy_parent_id IN (12,16,18,46) AND status=1'
policy_agreements = list(PolicyAgreement.objects.raw(query))
```

I'm getting the columns only in policy_agreement table, not getting columns of policy table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, because you do raw for the model `PolicyAgreement`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: You don't need a raw query for that, use a regular ORM query.

Comment: @BearBrown Got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To get the related objects append `.select_related("policy")`

First you do like this:

```
q=PolicyAgreement.objects.select_related("policy")
```

OR

```
q=policy.objects.select_related("PolicyAgreement")
```

as per your need

then print the query to see the raw query

```
print(q.query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the whole query in Django ORM.
The double underscore `__` is used to access related fields' properties in DB calls.

```
qs = PolicyAgreement.objects.select_related("policy")
qs = qs.filter(policy__policy_parent_id__in=(12,16,18,46), status=1)
```